# InvokeAction is suddenly failing

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, remote-action

This invokeAction used to work, and around Nov-1-15 stopped working (not sure if this is related to winter 16 or not)

It is included on a component, and the controller for the component is where the @RemoteAction is included. The {!$RemoteAction.xxx} code evaluates correctly (and it correctly fails if I remove the @RemoteAction annotation from the controller). The error appears when JS actually tries to invoke it.

**COMPONENT PAGE**

```
<apex:component controller="SuppressionRulesComponentController" allowDML="true">

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        getAllObjects();
    });


function getAllObjects() {
   //The line below is where it all fails
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.SuppressionRulesComponentController.getAllObjects}',
        function(result, event) {
             if (event.status) {         
                console.log(result);
            } else {
                //Error Handling
            }

        },      
        {buffer: true, escape: true}
    );

}

</script>
<apex:form >
</apex:form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public with sharing class SuppressionRulesComponentController {
@RemoteAction
    public static List<ObjectData> getAllObjects() {
        //Code goes here. This never executes
    }
}
```

**CONSOLE ERRORS**

```
(Warning) Controller not found for 'SuppressionRulesComponentController'
(Error) Unable to invoke action 'SuppressionRulesComponentController.getAllObjects': no controller and/or function found
```

Comment: Update: This is a SFDC bug, confirmed by their team.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008azEAAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This is a SFDC bug, confirmed by their team. [success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008azEAAQ](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008azEAAQ)